# SQLAlchemy insert rows to bridge table

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, associations

My question is **how to insert rows to a bridge table with SQLAlchemy**? I tried to look up [similar examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25669256/4490400), but they can't be directly applied here for 2 reasons: the bridge table has an additional column, and also, the referenced objects already exist and we don't want to recreate them.

Let's say I have 3 tables: socks, shoes and bridge. Bridge table has 3 columns:

- ForeignKey_socks
- ForeignKey_shoes
- Integer.

I've defined the database schema similarly as they do in [tutorials](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html) (see Many To Many -section), where "normal" tables are defined as classes and bridge table as a Table:

```
bridge = Table(...)
class Sock(Base): ...
class Shoe(Base): ...
```

I checked with psql that the database schema appears to be created correctly. I can insert Socks and Shoes. Errors come when I try to insert something into the bridge table.

First, I tried to insert rows like I would to any normal table:

```
link = bridge(...)
db.add(link)
db.commit()
```

The commit line yields `TypeError: Table object is not callable`. I assume this is because bridge is defined without the class declaration. I found another example where they do declare a class for the bridge table as well, so I tried that. If I declare a class instead of a "Table", my other classes break because of `Unresolved reference 'bridge'`. Doesn't matter which order the classes are declared. If I declare both a Table and a class, I get an `already defined` error. I also tried guessing various other syntax options, but I'm running out of ideas at this point.

Comment: You can find an answer to your main question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417906). As for why declaring `bridge` as a mapped class `Bridge` doesn't work, you need to replace `bridge` in your class definitions with with `Bridge.__table__`. (Of course you'd otherwise get "unresolved reference", because you haven't defined `bridge` anywhere!)

Comment: I adapted the example you linked. Now I don't get errors from adding links, but they don't end up in the database. Again, I can add to the regular tables, but not to the bridge table. I don't know how to debug this when it's not giving errors.

Comment: You'll have to post a [mcve]. It's not possible to debug if you only provide the symptoms and not what you're doing.

Comment: Posted MCVE now.

Comment: You have extra commas at the end of some of your lines.

Comment: Great, I now have a working MCVE based on the example you linked. Thanks again!