# sqlalchemy - could not map parent and child table with a seperate class

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

**Note : I know that this is a lengthy post and I have included too much of code, But I am not aware of what is important and what is not, as I am fairly new to SQLAlchemy. Really sorry for the inconvenience**

I am trying to map a many to many relationship between 2 tables, BUT at the same time I also have to add another field that can hold a null value in the beginning.

So far, I have tried following code:

[this example from github](https://gist.github.com/kirang89/10030736)

[this already provided solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417906/sqlalchemy-manytomany-secondary-table-with-additional-fields)

and have ended up with nothing working. Here is my code, please help me find what is my mistake. And if possible add a description to how it works as I am new to Python and SQLAlchemy

Test.py:

```
from app.Blueprints import db

class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column("name", db.Unicode)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Student.py:

```
from app.Blueprints import db, connection

class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "student_master"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    fname = db.Column("first_name", db.Unicode)
    lname = db.Column("last_name", db.Unicode)
    email = db.Column("email", db.Unicode, unique = True)
    passwd = db.Column("passwd", db.Unicode)


    def __init__(self, fname, lname, email):
        passwd = fname+" "+lname
        picture = "default.jpg"
        state = 1
        reg_date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.email = email
        self.passwd = passwd
```

Test_Student.py [The model that maps the test and student, with an extra field of grade]:

```
from app.models.Test import Test
from app.models.Student import Student
from app.Blueprints import db



class Test_Students(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test_student"
    test = db.Column("test_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('test.id'), primary_key = True)
    student = db.Column("student_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("student.id"), primary_key = True)
    grade = db.Column("grade", db.Float, nullable = True)

    tests = db.relationship(Test, backref="students")
    students = db.relationship(Student, backref="students")
```

And this is how I am creating new test:

```
if request.method == "POST" :
        from app.Blueprints import db
        from app.models.Test import Test
        from app.models.Test_students import Test_Students
        from app.models.Student import Student
        #register test
        newTest = Test(request.form.get("name"), request.form.get("date"), request.form.get("type"))
        db.session.add(newTest)
        db.session.commit()
        #map test with students
        StudentList = request.form.getlist("StudentList[]")
        for student in StudentList:
            stud = Student.query.get(student)
            newTest.students.append(stud)
```

When I try to execute I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Test_Students.students - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

Comment: `db.ForeignKey("student.id")`, yet the table mapped to `Student` is named `__tablename__ = "student_master"`.

Comment: the ``TestStudent`` table already has the **relationship** to ``Test`` and ``Student`` because of the foreign keys. You should put the ``db.relationship``'s into ``Test`` and ``Student`` - the ``tests`` relationship into ``Student`` and the ``students`` relationship into ``Tests``