# SQLAlchemy conditional many to many relationship with an additional column

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many

This is the way that I usually use for m2m relationship implementation.
(Brought from docs.sqlalchemy.org)

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child",
                    secondary=association_table,
                    backref="parents")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Is there any way for using additional columns at the `association_table` table?

So it should be like

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id')),
    Column('is_valid', Boolean, default=True)  # Add the validation column
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child",
                    secondary=association_table,
                    backref="parents")

    # How can I do implement this??
    valid_children = relationship("Child",
                    secondary="and_(association_table.left_id == Parent.id, association_table.right_id == Child.id)"

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I want to do query depends on `is_valid` column. How can I modify "secondary" attr in `Parent` table? Or should I fix the other part?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417906), `time_create` column has the same value for all children. But in this case, I need a flag that makes able to retrieve whether this connection is still alive or not.

For example, if you implement a one-on-one chatting, there will be a chatting room consist of two-person, right?
And the table should be like as below:

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id')),
    Column('is_left', Boolean, default=False)  # Whether the user left or not
)

class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = relationship("User",
                    secondary=association_table,
                    backref="matches")

    # How can I do implement this??
    exist_user = relationship("User",
                    secondary="and_(association_table.left_id == Parent.id, association_table.right_id == Child.id)"

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String, unique=True)
```

How can I do for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy ManyToMany secondary table with additional fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417906/sqlalchemy-manytomany-secondary-table-with-additional-fields)

Comment: Also consider why you need a valid flag.  If the relationship is not valid, would it be acceptable to just delete the record from your secondary table?  Otherwise, use the above with association proxies.

Comment: @bjdduck Bc I still need the record after I deleted (or deactivated) the connection.

Comment: After got a duplicated warning, I added some changes.